# Forces on a closed container that can electromagnetically suspend objects

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, forces, collision

If you have a closed container (without air or other fluids, only with the object inside) that can electromagnetically suspend or maintain (not like if the container walls are covered with a single piece of magnet, more like if the walls have electromagnets that can change his polarity to maintain the object suspended, i show what i mean in the image below) an object in its center and if you drop this container what will happen to that object? Would it move? For example, when you put water in a plastic cup, and put a floating object and drop it?
A eletromagnetic field can transmit kinetic energy?

The red part are the electromagnets, and the black circle are the container.

[image: The red part are the electromagnets, and the black circle are the container]

Comment: If you drop this container, then the EM field will change wrt your lab frame. The original electric and magnetic field components (in case of static container) will mix and produce a new pair of electric and magnetic fields. Consequently the Lorentz force acting on the suspended object will change (when viewed from your lab frame) and so the equilibrium will be disturbed

Comment: Note that when you put a floating object in water in a cup and drop it, the object will not move w.r.t. the cup, since the whole system is being uniformly accelerated.

Comment: @KP99 I forgot to mention, but the wall of the container is not a magnet which would imply that the container has two fixed poles, the wall of the container could change his polarity or would have parts in it that could change his polarity to maintain the object suspended, it not like when you have three magnets N/S - S/N - N/S and if you slightly move one of the magnets at the ends the magnet in the middle would rotate to match the poles.

Comment: You should remind yourself that your container is on the surface of a rotating planet when thinking about these questions.